# Helm: install single redis instance from chart dependency

Tags: kubernetes, service, redis, dependencies, kubernetes-helm

In `Chart.yaml` I specified dependency:

```
dependencies:
  - name: redis
    version: 15.0.3
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

In `deployment.yaml` I specify service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
      app: redis
  name: redis-svc
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 6355
  selector:
      app: redis
```

But what I see after `kubectl get all`:

```
service/redis-svc               ClusterIP   None             <none>        6355/TCP   36s
statefulset.apps/myapp-redis-master     0/1     37s
statefulset.apps/myapp-redis-replicas   0/3     37s
```

I want single redis instance as Service. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Helm supports passing arguments to dependent sub-charts. You can override the architecture of your `redis` sub-chart by adding this to your `values.yaml` file.

```
redis:
  architecture: standalone
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the parameter for a standalone redis:

```
architecture=standalone
```

For example, install redis via imperative command:

```
helm install my-redis-release -n default --set architecture=standalone bitnami/redis
```